# map() is not rendering html elements

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping, react-props

I had spent 4hrs in this issue but can't figure out what's the problem. Through **props** I had passed an array(props.content) and wanted to render each element with `<h4> tag`(not specific) but I can't. It works when I try to `console.log` each elements of array.

```
import classes from "./Memes.module.css";
const Memes = (props) => {
        
       return (
         <div className={classes.memes__body}>
         {Array.prototype.forEach.call(props.content,items=>{
             console.log(items)
         })}
          </div> 
       );
}


export default Memes;
```

**Output** -

[image: When I try to console.log then it works fine]

but It didn't work when I run the same to render all items in some `html tags`.

```
import classes from "./Memes.module.css";

const Memes = (props) => {
        
       return (
         <div className={classes.memes__body}>
         {Array.prototype.forEach.call(props.content,items=>{
             <h1>{items}</h1>
         })}
          </div> 
       );
}


export default Memes;
```

**OutPut**
Doesn't work.

**Note** - Here `props.content` is an array of strings.

Fetch_memes.js (Parent one)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Memes from "./Memes";

const Fetch_memes = () => {

    const [image, setImage] = useState();
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const memes = async () => {
        const response = await  fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json');
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
    
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const img = responseData.data.children[0].data.thumbnail;
        const memesCollection = [];
        memesCollection.push("If you can Code then this doesn't mean that your are developer");

        for(let i=0 ; i<20 ; i++){
            memesCollection.push(responseData.data.children[i].data.title);
        }
        
        console.log(memesCollection[1]);
        setImage(img);
        setText(memesCollection);
        }
        memes();
      }, []);

  return (
      <Memes src={image} content={text}/>
  );
}

export default Fetch_memes;
```

Comment: same problem! someone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use return in your code:

```
import classes from "./Memes.module.css";

const Memes = (props) => {
        
    return (
      < >
      {props.content.map((items)=>{
          return <h1>{items}</h1>
      })}
       </> 
    );
}


export default Memes;
```

Comment: thankyou for your suggestion! But this didn't work :(

Comment: @Uttam I've edited the code, check now that will run. Added `map`.

Comment: Hey I had done like this already but it didn't worked that time. But now it's working..Thankyou for the help

Comment: @Uttam if this answer helped you then please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Uttam what error you are getting, it is working perfectly fine for me. Did you add another piece of code?

Comment: props.content.map() is not a function

Comment: @Uttam You said before that `props.content` is an array of strings. I did same and it works for me. Have you checked if `props.content` is still **array of strings**

Comment: Yes, I had checked it and you can also see I had pasted the output also.

Comment: @Uttam all i can see is this ` **OutPut** Doesn't work.`. What is the exact error you are getting . Are you sure `image` and `text` is setting properly? Have you changed your code to use `map` instead? I can still see `Array.prototype.forEach.call` in your above mentioned code?

Answer (score 1):

you can either use

```
{props.content.map(items=>{
             return <h4>{items}</h4>
         })}
```

or replace  `{}` by `()`and react returns the value by default:

```
{props.content.map(items=>(<h4>{items}</h4>))}
```

---

UPDATE: try this:

```
import classes from "./Memes.module.css";
import React from "react"
const Memes = ({content})=>{
  return (
    <div>
      {content.map(item=>(<h1>{item}</h1>))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Memes;
```

let me know the result.

Comment: THis didn't worked, I tried this earlier also :(

Comment: have you tried not using `Array.prototype.forEach.call`? and use `props.content.map` directly? also, what is the name of props you have passed to this element?

Comment: I had passed an array of strings which is  `props.content` I had fetched those array of strings from an API and yes I trie `props.content.map()` but I don't know why it runs sometimes but  sometimes it don't run and suddenly says `props.content.map()` is not a function.

Comment: it happened again, when II reload my page got an error.  I don't know why it runs sometimes but  sometimes it don't run and suddenly says `props.content.map()` is not a function.

Comment: I think it is better to share your parent component as well.

Comment: I have tried it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-haze-87dgk?file=/src/Memes.js:0-161

Comment: @Uttam did my answer help you?

Comment: @Abbashin I had upvoted your answer I had tried the way you suggested earlier but it works sometimes and sometimes not. I think the problem is with the API